# How to flip an img in Pygame, having trouble in my code?

Tags: python, image, transform, pygame, flip

I'm having trouble flipping a sprite in pygame (I can get it to go right but I want the img to flip on the left key),
I researched how to flip an image and found the `pygame.transform.flip`, but as a beginner to pygame, I'm not sure how to use it, and the tutorials aren't making sense to me.
Can anyone help me with the code below (I'm not sure if I even put the self.img1 for the flip in the right place)?

```
import pygame, sys, glob 
from pygame import *

class Player:
    def __init__(self):      
        self.x = 200     
        self.y = 300   
        self.ani_speed_init = 6
        self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init 
        self.ani = glob.glob("walk\Pinks_w*.png")
        self.ani.sort() 
        self.ani_pos = 0
        self.ani_max = len(self.ani)-1
        self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani[0])
        self.img1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.ani[0], True, False)

        self.update(0)

    def update(self, pos):
        if pos != 0: 
            self.ani_speed-=1
            self.x+=pos
            if self.ani_speed == 0:
                self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani[self.ani_pos])
                self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
                if self.ani_pos == self.ani_max:
                    self.ani_pos = 0
                else:
                    self.ani_pos+=1
        screen.blit(self.img,(self.x,self.y))

h = 400
w = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player1 = Player()
pos = 0

while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = -1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = 0

    player1.update(pos)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Your code snippet is far longer than necessary.  For example, you have including keyboard and positioning functionality, but that is not relevant to your problem.  It is your responsibility as a querent to create a code snippet which is as small and self-contained as possible.

Comment: You don't want to be `pygame.image.load()`ing every game loop. Do it once at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Player` class is not very well readable. As, your names are not easy to understand.
In my version of your code, all I have changed is the names and I have added a check for the value of `pos` and applied the flip if needed. So, you may need to change the check (if condition), to get the desired results.

And Yes, you don't have a `pygame.Sprite`, so, the word sprite is misleading, in this case.

My version of your `Player` class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):      
        self.x = 200  
        self.y = 300   
        self.speed_init = 6
        self.images = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in glob.glob("walk\Pinks_w*.png")]
        self.index = 0
        self.max_index = len(self.images)-1
        self.speed = 0
        self.img = self.images[self.index]

    def update(self, pos):
        if pos != 0:
            self.speed -= 1
            self.x += pos
            if not self.speed:
                self.speed = self.speed_init
                if self.index < self.max_index:
                    self.index += 1
                else:
                    self.index = 0
            self.img = self.images[self.index]
        # change True to False if needed, or change the operator.
        if pos > 0:
            self.img = pygame.transform.flip(self.img,True,False)
        screen.blit(self.img,(self.x,self.y))
```

**Update**
There was a small problem with the `update` function. The problem was that since speed was always constant and not `0`, the `if not self.speed:` did not work. So, change the `update` function to this:

```
def update(self, pos):
    if pos != 0:
        self.speed -= 1
        self.x += pos
        # no more self.speed checks
        if self.index < self.max_index:
            self.index += 1
        else:
            self.index = 0
        self.img = self.images[self.index]
    # change True to False if needed, or change the operator.
    if pos < 0:
        self.img = pygame.transform.flip(self.img,True,False)
    screen.blit(self.img,(self.x,self.y))
```

**Update 2**
It seems that there is some kind of typo in your code,
Here's (my version of) the Code, The whole thing.

```
import pygame, sys, glob 
from pygame import *

class Player:
    def __init__(self):      
        self.x = 200  
        self.y = 300   
        self.speed_init = 6
        self.images = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in glob.glob("walk\Pinks_w*.png")]
        self.index = 0
        self.max_index = len(self.images)-1
        self.speed = 0
        self.img = self.images[self.index]
        print self.max_index

    def update(self, pos):
        if pos != 0:
            self.speed -= 1
            self.x += pos
            print self.index, self.max_index
            if self.index < self.max_index:
                self.index += 1
            else:
                self.index = 0
            self.img = self.images[self.index]
        # change True to False if needed, or change the operator.
        if pos < 0:
            self.img = pygame.transform.flip(self.img,True,False)
        screen.blit(self.img,(self.x,self.y))

h = 400
w = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player1 = Player()
pos = 0

while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(20)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 2
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = -2
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = 0

    player1.update(pos)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help with the code it worked well, except it won't cycle through the images like it did before (when I was using self.ani = glob.glob("walk\Pinks_w*.png"). I have a series of four imgs named Pinks_w1 through w4 (to give the appearance of walking) but it just stays on the first img when I inserted the "self.images = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in glob.glob("walk\Pinks*.png")]" does anyone have any suggestions, on how to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: when I inserted the edited update function it came back with an error that said, line 58 in <module> Attribute Error: Player instance has no attribute 'update'. I'm not sure what this means as I have "player1.update(pos)" on line 58?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but there still seems to be some errors in which i'm not able to fix. The terminal displayed two when trying to run. Line 35 in player1 = Player() has a trace back error. And line 13, in __init__ self.images[self.index] Index Error: list index out of range. Not sure what to do here either? This will will be the last question, before I decide to try and rewrite the code from the beginning to get it to work.

Comment: I copied and pasted the entire code again, it still threw the two errors above again.

Comment: Your images are not loading... Check your filenames and use absolute paths if possible...

Comment: that was the issue, the img path was wrong. Thank you for your help, the code now runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

To flip, you would do:

```
# input
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_RIGHT:
        flip_x = True
    elif event.key == K_LEFT:
        flip_x = False
    elif event.key == K_UP:
        flip_y = True
    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
        flip_y = False

# then to flip
new_image = pygame.transform.flip(original_image, flip_x, flip_y)
```

Comment: invalid syntax, you must use `==` instead of `=` in conditions